# Witcher 1 number of blows

Tags: the-witcher

In the Witcher 1 some of the talents regarding styles mention things like '1st attack in sequence. Consists of 2 blows.'

As I unlocked the second level in strong style which says '2nd attack in sequence. Consists of 2 blows.' So the attack in sequence is, I suppose, the second attack after timing the click when the sword indicator is on fire.

If this is correct then this second attack should have an animation consisting of 2 blows, but Geralt only jumps in the air and hits once. How am I supposed to know that this talent actually works when I unlock it?

This example is just for strong style, I also noticed that for fast style. It says 5 blows, but it looks like he does 4. Even the damage number display less times than the number of blows.